# what is the standard naming convention for a private member with an expression body in C#

Tags: c#

I've read the naming convention in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/coding-conventions.

However, I couldn't find the answer for this example below:

```cs
public class A
{
    private int _b;
    
    // Should I use "_" + camel case to name this member:
    private string _c => _b.ToString();
    
    // Or should I use pascal case to name this member:
    private string C => b.ToString();
}
```

1. Should the member `_c` or `C` be called "private property" with a getter method or "private calculated field"? why?
2. If we want to use a member private internally with an expression body(`=>`) similar to this example. What is the naming convention for it?

Comment: _"However, it didn't mention this case:"_ - well **yes it did**.  All three members in your code are _fields_ and so the following guideline applies _["Use camel casing ("camelCasing") when naming private or internal fields, and prefix them with _"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/coding-conventions)_.   The fact that you are using `=>` is incidental.

Comment: Opinion, not an answer. I'd go with `C` (i.e., PascalCase) since it's a read-only property. It's the property-ness that makes it PascalCase, it's public/private-ness doesn't matter. @MickyD: the `=>` certainly matters, it makes `C` a read-only property,  not a field

Answer (score 1):

As a common usage style in C#, *fields* start with a lowercase letter, *properties* start with a capital letter. Generally, fields begin with the `_` character. If the data member is a *field*, it would be more appropriate to call it `_c`, and if it's a *property*, it would be called `C`.

*Properties* show fields. *Fields* are privately defined within a class and must be accessed via the get and set *properties*. *Properties* provide a level of abstraction that allows you to modify fields without affecting the external path accessed by clients using your class.

In this example, you don't need to define a field or property if you want clients to always use the `_b` variable as a string:

```cs
public class A
{
    private int _b;

    public string GetBAsString()
    {
        return _b.ToString();
    }
}
```

---

###### References

- [What is the difference between a field and a property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295104/what-is-the-difference-between-a-field-and-a-property)

Comment: I have updated my question, what if I need a private member and with an expression body and its output is taking existing filed into account. Should this member be called a "property" or "field". I know almost always properties are public, but can't it be private?

Comment: A property is _field-like_ in appearance and usage, but runs code for a _getter_ and/or a _setter_. It doesn't matter if it's private or public. Your `C` is a private, read-only property (the getter calls `_b.ToString()`, there is no setter)